# Merge columns from different sheets into specific order

Tags: excel, merge, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file with three sheets of annual data. For example:

**Sheet 1** is for year 2006

```
               Site1       Site2      Site4
Jan             10          12         14
Feb             0           15          9
```

**Sheet 2** is for year 2007

```
               Site1       Site3      Site4
Jan             14          10         18
Feb             4           16          2
```

**Sheet 3** is for year 2008

```
               Site2       Site3      Site4      Site5
Jan             12          13          7          12
Feb             5           13          5          16
```

In **Sheet 4**, I want to combine these data under the specific `Site_number` (if the `Site_number` is unique, I want to add a column for that data). For example:

**Sheet 4** should look like this:

```
                       Site1       Site2      Site3       Site4       Site5
2006    Jan             10          12                      14
        Feb             0           15                       9
2007    Jan             14                     10           18
        Feb             4                      16            2
2008    Jan                         12         13            7         12
        Feb                          5         13            5         16
```

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: Please describe the problem (i.e., not just the objective) and what you have tried.

Comment: @pnuts, there are 100 sites in all - thanks

Comment: The sites are actually named after places and not simply numbered like in my example, so I am trying to use VLookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very many way of achieving your objective and with the columns apparently already sorted I would be tempted merely to add blank columns until each sheet has each Site in the same column. However instead with a lookup function something like:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$10:$F$12,ROW(),IFERROR(MATCH(C$1,$C$10:$F$10,0),"")),"")
```

copied across and down to suit should work, provided Row1 has a complete list of unique Sites and, for the purposes of illustration, your original data is in the same sheet but moved down to start at Row10 and across one column (the latter to allow for manual addition of the year).

I'd suggest one sheet at a time and then merely copy and add/append into a new sheet as required.